# Prove that $\mathscr B=\{D(z,\epsilon)\} \cup \{E((x,0),\epsilon)\}$ be basis for a topology on $A.$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

[image]

Case 1

$B_1, B_2 \in \{D(z,\epsilon)\}$,

case (a) $B_1 \cap B_2=\phi$

case (b)$B_1 \cap B_2\neq \phi$
 $x\in B_1 \cap B_2$. 
[image]

Geometrically, I am able to see an element of  $\{D(z,\epsilon)\}$,$B_3(say)$ such a way that $x\in B_3$ and $B_3\subset B_1 \cap B_2$. I took radius of $B_3$ as $dist(x, bound {(B_1\cap B_2)})/2$. Am I correct.

Case 2.
$B_1 \in \{D(z,\epsilon)\}$ and $B_2 \in \{E((x,0),\epsilon)\}$[image]

Here also I choose radius of $B_3$ less than $dist(x, bound {(B_1\cap B_2)})$.

Case 3
 $B_1,B_2 \in \{E((x,0),\epsilon)\}$

[image]

Here also I choose radius of $B_3$ less than $dist(x,\overline { bound {(B_1\cap B_2)})$.

Case 4

[image]

Do I left any case here? Is my idea of proof correct? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Note in order to check a collection $\mathscr B$ of subsets of $A$ is a basis you have to check following two things

1) For each $a\in A$ there is at least one element $B$ containing $a$, which is trivially follow.

2) If $a$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $a$  such that $B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

You have taken $a$ only from the set $\{(x,y)\in R^2 : y>0\}$ i.e. you have to consider also the case when $a\in \{(x,y)\in R^2 : y=0\}$.

Comment: How  consider the case when $a\in \{(x,y)\in R^2 : y=0\}$?

Comment: (1) Sorry sir I forgot to prove (1). I got the proof of that too.

Comment: That is same as you done in the last case, what you have to do in the last picture is nothing but this - place $ a$ on $X$-axis. And find an element from $\{E((x,0),\epsilon)\}$  contained in both $B_1$ and $B_2$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$

Comment: from your comment, I have considered it as case4. Now, Is my proof corect?

Comment: Yeah, that is right now.

Comment: thank you very much sir.

Comment: sorry it is not closure, but boundary of $B_2 \cap B_1$

Comment: Can you say something more about your last comment, I mean what you trying to say .

Comment: I meant that I should have to take radius of $B_3$ as $dist(x, bound(B_1\cap B_2))$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84234/discussion-between-users-and-math-geek).